# Mean and Variance of SSE

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-algebra, quadratic-form

First, let

\begin{equation}
SSE = \overrightarrow{y}'(I - H) \overrightarrow{y}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
\overrightarrow{y} \sim MN(\textbf{X} \overrightarrow{\beta}, \sigma^{2}I) \\
H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
E(SSE) = E(\overrightarrow{y}'(I - H) \overrightarrow{y}) = k_{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=>  k_{1} = tr[(I-H) \sigma^{2}I] + (\textbf{X}\overrightarrow{\beta})'(I-H)\textbf{X}\overrightarrow{\beta} \\
= \sigma^{2}(tr(I)-tr(H)) + 0 \\
= \sigma^{2}[n-(k+1)]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Var(SSE) = Var(\overrightarrow{y}'(I - H) \overrightarrow{y}) = k_{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=>  k_{2} = 2tr[((I-H) \sigma^{2}I)^{2}] + 2(\textbf{X}\overrightarrow{\beta})'(I-H)(\sigma^{2}I(I-H))\textbf{X}\overrightarrow{\beta}
\end{equation}
and using a similar argument as the expectation:
\begin{equation}
=>  k_{2} = \sigma^{4}[n-(k+1)]
\end{equation}

I know my mean is correct but I'm thinking my variance is wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good to me **except** you forgot to multiply by $2$ for the first term in the expression for $\mathrm{Var}(SSE)$. So the final answer for the variance should be double what you wrote. By the way, the formula for $\mathrm{Var}(\mathbf{y}'(I-H)\mathbf{y})$ should have a coefficient of $4$ rather than $2$ for the second term ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Variance)), but it doesn't matter since that part becomes $0$ anyway.

Also, another way to check your answer would be to recall that $$\frac{(n-(k+1))\widehat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-(k+1)}$$ in this model. You can then take the mean and variance of both sides (using the formula for mean and variance of a chi-squared random variable).